# How do you unpack a nested iterator/iterable as an argument to a variadic function?

Tags: python, iterable

Consider the following snippet of code written in Python-style syntax:

```python
class k:   
    def __init__(*args):
        self._args = args

    def mimethod(self, attrname:str):   
        return type(self)(getattr(arg, attrname) for arg in self._args)
```

Notice that `getattr(arg, attrname) for arg in self._args` returns an iterator.

We are in danger of having the following two undesirable things happen:

- an iterator is assigned to `self._args[0]`
- `len(args) == 1`.

How do you flatten a deeply nested iterator which is passed into a variadic function such that each string of length one becomes an element of args?

A second example of passing an iterator into a variadic function is shown below:

```python
import sys
import io

def variadic_function(*args, file_stream = sys.stdout):
    print("\n".join(str(arg) for arg in args, file=sys.stdout)

strm = io.StringIO()

# names = tuple(x.strip() for x in "LUciA, SoFiA, mArIA, MARTInA, pAuLa, LuCaS, hUgO, mArTiN, dAnIeL, pAbLo".split(","))   

names = ('LUciA', 'SoFiA', 'mArIA', 'MARTInA', 'pAuLa', 'LuCaS', 'hUgO', 'mArTiN', 'dAnIeL', 'pAbLo')

variadic_function(name[0].upper()+ name[1:].lower() for name in names, file=strm)

print(strm.getvalue())
```

Comment: Not just "in danger of", _that's what happens_. If you want it to be separate arguments, _unpack it_, but then there's no point using an iterator because it has to be consumed immediately anyway. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve here?

Comment: @johrsharpe I probably should have asked something like, "how do we automatically unpack an iterator" that is `result = call_to_foo(iterator)` and `result = call_to_foo(*iterator)` should return the same object. If `args[0]` is an iterator, then we have to flatten `args` into a single un-nested iterator or container or list or tuple, or something like that. If `args` is un-nested, then we have to un-nest `args`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why did you remove the tag "variadic-functions"? I think the fact that the OP is asking about potentially deeply nested iterators implies that we need variadic functions.

Answer (score 1):

**You can unpack an iterator `iter` directly for a function call by writing `f(*iter)`.**

You mention that `getattr(arg, attrname) for arg in self._args` produces an iterator. This is correct in your context, but for a more general statement, it would be better to say that the parenthesized expression `(getattr(arg, attrname) for arg in self._args)` produces a *generator*. (A generator is a kind of iterator.)

In your two examples, we thus use parentheses, to let Python know what the asterisk is being applied to:

```
return type(self)(*(getattr(arg, attrname) for arg in self._args))

variadic_function(*(name[0].upper()+ name[1:].lower() for name in names), file=strm)
```

You talk about the possibility of a "deeply nested" iterator (iterators within iterators), which would require more work and a recursive function. You also mention "each string of length one" becoming an argument to the function (thus `'abc'` would become `('a', 'b', 'c')`), but it seems that this is not needed for your two examples. That said, if you do need to do the latter, an asterisk before a string will do the trick:

```
print(*'abc')
# output: a b c
```

---

If you need to unpack an iterator `iter` for a purpose other than using its output as the arguments of a function call, you can convert them into a tuple or list as follows:

```
tuple(iter)
list(iter)
```

Concretely:

```
tuple(range(5))
# output: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
list(range(5))
# output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You could in principle unpack the resulting tuple or list for a function call by using `*`

```
print(*tuple(range(5)))
print(*list(range(5)))
# output (in both cases): 0 1 2 3 4
```

but writing `print(*range(5))` is more straightforward.

(Executing `print(tuple(range(5)))` or `print(list(range(5)))` without an asterisk would print `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)` or `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, respectively.)

Answer (score 0):

I will now answer your subsequent question:

> How do we automatically unpack an iterable? If it is nested, we have to un-nest it.

This line above was modified slightly from your original wording:

- I assume you mean *iterable* instead of *iterator*, because `*expr` as a function parameter [requires that `expr` be an *iterable*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-49). This makes the question more general because all iterators are iterables.
- I assume you mean "if `args` is nested" instead of "if `args` is un-nested".

That is, I interpret your question as follows:

**How do you unpack a nested iterator/iterable as an argument to a variadic function?**

My solution correctly handles **deep nesting** and **strings of length one**.

```
import collections.abc

def unpack_iterable(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, str):
        return arg
    lst = []
    for x in arg:
        if isinstance(x, collections.abc.Iterable):
            lst.extend(unpack_iterable(x))
        else:
            lst.append(x)
    return lst

nested_iterable = (range(3), ['abc', '456', (78, range(91, 94)), range(101, 104)])
unpack_iterable(nested_iterable)
# output:
# [0, 1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', '4', '5', '6', 78, 91, 92, 93, 101, 102, 103]
```

The check at the beginning of the function prevents infinite recursion because even strings of length 1 are iterables.

Note that the function `unpack_iterable` assumes that its argument is iterable. We can thus use it as follows:

```
my_arg = unpack_iterable(nested_iterable) if isinstance(nested_iterable, collections.abc.Iterable) else nested_iterable
print(*my_arg)
# output:
# 0 1 2 a b c 4 5 6 78 91 92 93 101 102 103

# compare:
print(*nested_iterable)
# output:
# range(0, 3) ['abc', '456', (78, range(91, 94)), range(101, 104)]
```

Moving the check into the function definition would slow down our code, because that check would be performed after each recursive call. However, we need to check before each recursive call as well, to decide whether to use `lst.extend` or `lst.append`. One could of course define a thin wrapper taking care of this check only once:

```
def unwrapIterable_functionCall(f, it):
    if isinstance(it, collections.abc.Iterable):
        return f(*unpack_iterable(it))
    else:
        return f(it)
```

We can use it as follows:

```
unwrapIterable_functionCall(print, nested_iterable)
# output:
# 0 1 2 a b c 4 5 6 78 91 92 93 101 102 103

unwrapIterable_functionCall(print, 'xyz')
# output:
# x y z

unwrapIterable_functionCall(print, 987)
# output:
# 987
```